# How can I pass touch events to react-draggable

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently using react-draggable to implement resizing table columns 
see example: https://codesandbox.io/s/j30k46l7xw

This is not working on most mobile devices nor the devtools[image]
I was wondering if there is a way for react-draggable to accept touch events. I went through the repo docs and issues and it seems like it's been implemented. I just can't figure it out

Comment: This is working just fine for me on mobile (as well as simulating touch in devtools)... I am able to resize columns without issue..

Comment: is it on an Iphone or Ipad? cause those work for me aswell, problem is android mobile devices

Comment: This is working on a Pixel 3 for me.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/MnIrEIy.gif

Answer (score 1):

I think react draggable will get confused if you are using onClick event on its parent div/component

use onTouchStart along with onClick event

```
onClick={(e) => handleSomething(e)}
onTouchStart={(e) => handleSomething(e)}
```